# JS and JQuery, passing arguments to functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, arguments

so I just started making a webpage for a change and I want to animate some buttons and so on. So what i want to do is write a function wich takes an object (in this case an ) and declares functions for the hover-event. The function works totaly fine in this (not usefull) version:

```js
    function hoverOver() {
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#FormA").hover(function(){
                $("#ButtonA").animate({marginLeft:"5px", opacity:"1"}, "fast");
            }, function(){
                $("#ButtonA").animate({marginLeft:"0px", opacity:"0.5"}, "fast");
            });
        });
```

But in order to use the function on multiple Buttons, I want to write it like this:

```js
    function hoverOver(source) {    
        $(document).ready(function(){
            source.parent().hover(function(){
                source.animate({marginLeft:"5px", opacity:"1"}, "fast");
            }, function(){
                source.animate({marginLeft:"0px", opacity:"0.5"}, "fast");
            });
        });
    }
    // this is how I want to call the function with multiple Buttons
    hoverOver($("#ButtonA"));
```

I also tought that it would work if I pass the source-variable through all the functions like this:

```js
    function hoverOver(source) {
        $(document).ready(function(source){ //  <-- here
            source.parent().hover(function(source){ //  <-- here
                source.animate({marginLeft:"5px", opacity:"1"}, "fast");
            }, function(source){ // <-- and here
                source.animate({marginLeft:"0px", opacity:"0.5"}, "fast");
            });
        });
    }
    // this is how I want to call the function with multiple Buttons
    hoverOver($("#ButtonA"));
```

So where is my problem? I know this way of coding JS is not the best way and specialy with JS, HTML and CSS there are million ways to do it but I realy started like 4 days ago. ;)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery you might as well extend its prototype, like this:

```
$.fn.hoverOver = function(){
    this.each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.parent().hover(function(){
             $this.animate({marginLeft:"5px", opacity:"1"}, "fast"); 
        }, function(){
             $this.animate({marginLeft:"0", opacity:"0.5"}, "fast"); 
        });
    });
}
```

And then bind it to any element like this;

```
$("#buttonA").hoverOver();
```

or this:

```
$(".buttonHover").hoverOver();
```

Comment: Mhh,I see. So you make some function wich you can acess with fuu.hoverOver() and it takes the element wich called the function and does stuff with it, right? Right now it does not work but I will get around the problem I had before. :) I will see what i can do with it, thanks. :)

Comment: If you use jQuery $ is a shortcut for an object of class jQuery. $.fn.hoverOver = function() is adding a method to this class. and when you call $("#buttonA") you create new instance of jQuery class from this selector. And then you invoke this method you have created. But remember, the form you're binding hover event to must be this button direct parent, or the script won't work.

Comment: Ha, I made it. :) So what I missed was adding the $(document).ready() - line. It works now, thanks for your help. :)